# Установка коректного значения для antMatcher'а для страницы index

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Подключил к web проекту Spring Security, чтобы защитить страницы сайта.В классе SecurityConfig, который расширяет WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, есть метод protected void configure(HttpSecurity http),который выглядит как-то так :

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().formLogin().successHandler(new MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).failureForwardUrl("/login?error");
}
```

И так, есть antMatcher в котором я задаю url адреса, которые доступны только авторизованным пользователям(насколько я понимаю), но я хочу, чтобы главная страница по адресу "/" была также доступна для всех пользователей, в том числе и не авторизованных. Посмотрев по другим вопросам нашёл решение этой проблемы в виде `public void configure(WebSecurity web)`:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/");
}
```

Но дело в том, что в данном коде ничего не работает, я не могу перейти на главную страницу без авторизации. Мне кажется, что дело в неправильном параметре `antMatchers("/")`, потому что тоже самое для другого адреса работает

Comment: Каким образом задается секюрити конфиг?

Comment: через аннотации `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration`

Comment: Чёрт,нашёл ошибку(во всяком случае после удалению оно начало работать) в методе `public String index2(Model model, Principal principal) {
        model.addAttribute("message","You are logged in as "+principal.getName());
        return "index";
    }`  ловил ошибку потому что principal=null